LWR Navigation from one LWC compnent to another
I have 2 LWC component applicationPage and gettingStarted and I want to use the page in LWR.
ApplicationPage is having a button which should navigate from applicationPage to GettingStarted in the same site.
I have tried to use Lightning navigation but it is showing invalid page
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                //url: `${basePath}/gettingStarted`
            }
        });

I have also used
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                url: c__gettingStarted
            }
        });

How can navigate from one LWC component to another LWC component in LWR
